# Ex and Vi: buffers and regexes

Tags: vi, buffer, regular-expression

I want to put regex matches to buffer but cannot get even simpler example `y   :.put myNewBuffer` return msg `[line] [put] [buffer]` working ie how to put something to buffer?

**So to regular expressions and ex**

1. what does `(.,.)~ replaces the previous regular expression with the previous replacement pattern from a substitution` mean? Some example helpful, source of the [quote](http://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/usd/10.exref/paper.pdf).
2. please, give some examples how you use regexes with ex. For example, how can you buffer areas between starting word having `h` as the first character until the word ending to `s` character?
3. What about if the last thing only on a line ie ending word is the word ending to `s` or the end of line `$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vim manual may be a better and more up-to-date than that old Ex manual.  Most likely, you will be using ex that comes with vim on most modern Linux distributions.  To get help in Vim use :help, to get help on a specific command like the Ex command ~, use `:help :~`.  All Ex commands are preceded with a : in Vim.  I think (.,.) is simply used to denote a range may be specified as in 2,8 to mean lines 2 through 8 or 1,$ ($ represents last line) for every line in a file.  In Vim, typing `:1,$~` means run the Ex command ~ on every line in the file.

1. Vim say `:~` is "Repeat last substitute with same substitute string but with last used search pattern."  A substitution is normally written as `:s/pattern/string/`  This looks for a pattern on a line and replaces it with string.  `:~` repeats last substitute command, but uses the most recent search for pattern.
2. Try this pattern: `/\<h.*s\>`

/ is used to start a search in Ex/Vim, \< means match start of word, h matches h, .* where . matches any single character and * repeats that zero or more times so .* means match zero or more characters.  s matches s, \> matches end of word.

1. Try this pattern `/words\?$`

$ means end of line when used in a pattern match, and \? means previous character is optional.  This will match word or words at the end of a line.

Comment: Does this answer your questions?